# digitalocean and google domain settings

Tags: url, dns, webserver

I have a problem when I access to my url.

If I enter myurl.com on browser, it redirects to my digital ocean server and shows the contents correctly. However, the url on the browser is changed to ip address:port/index right away.

I'm not sure what to change to show up with correct url (myurl.com) on the browser so that the users cannot see my ip address directly.

Below are the pictures of current setting.

Thank you in advance.

[DNS Records on digital ocean side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovdZg.png)

[DNS setting on google domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSjAG.png)